# Cannot pass parameter to cli script anymore using -D

Tags: jboss, command-line-interface, keycloak

I use some script for Keycloak configuration purpose.
Until now, I used Keycloak 2.5.5.Final. I just upgraded to Keycloak 4.5.0.Final and I have a problem.

My script was called like that :

```
E:\...\scripts>keycloak-cli.bat --connect --controller=localhost:9990 
-DdeployDir=E:\\...\\config\bin -DmysqlHost=localhost -DmysqlPort=3306 
-DmysqlUser=KeycloakSQL -DmysqlPwd=somepwd -DadminPort=9991 -DhttpPort=8081 
-DhttpsPort=8444 --file=E:\...\cli\keycloak_wildfly.cli
```

Keycloak-cli.bat being :

```
@echo off

REM set NOPAUSe to avoid to block the cmd when a wildfly cli script is executed
set NOPAUSE=true

REM set the java_home environment variable
set JAVA_HOME=E:\...\jdk

call "E:\...\keycloak\bin\jboss-cli.bat" %*
```

and keycloak_wildfly.cli being :

```
#batch

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create db datasource                                                                                                          
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
if (outcome != success) of /subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=mariadb:read-resource
    /subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=mariadb:add(driver-name=mariadb,driver-module-name=org.mariadb,driver-xa-datasource-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver)
end-if

if (outcome != success) of /subsystem=security/security-domain=KeycloakDatabaseLogin/:read-resource
    /subsystem=security/security-domain=KeycloakDatabaseLogin/:add(cache-type=default)
    /subsystem=security/security-domain=KeycloakDatabaseLogin/authentication=classic:add(login-modules=[{"code"=>"SecureIdentity", "flag"=>"required", "module-options"=>[("username"=>"${mysqlUser}"),("password"=>"-123456789")]}])
end-if

# Modify the default datasource (if already exist) to use our mariaDB
if (outcome == success) of /subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS:read-resource
    /subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS:write-attribute(name="jta",value="false")
    /subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS:write-attribute(name="use-ccm",value="false")
    /subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS:write-attribute(name="enabled",value="true")
    /subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS:write-attribute(name="jndi-name",value="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS")
    /subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS:write-attribute(name="max-pool-size",value="10")
    /subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS:write-attribute(name="min-pool-size",value="5")
    /subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS:write-attribute(name="driver-name",value="mariadb")
    /subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS:write-attribute(name="connection-url",value="jdbc:mysql://${mysqlHost}:${mysqlPort}/KeycloakDB")
    /subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS:undefine-attribute(name="password")
    /subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS:undefine-attribute(name="user-name")
    /subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS:write-attribute(name="security-domain",value="KeycloakDatabaseLogin") 
end-if
# Else create a new datasource if not available
if (outcome != success) of /subsystem=datasources/data- source=KeycloakDS:read-resource
    /subsystem=datasources/data-source="KeycloakDS":add(jta="false",use-ccm="false",enabled="true",jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS,max-pool-size=10,min-pool-size=5,driver-name=mariadb,connection-url=jdbc:mysql://${mysqlHost}:${mysqlPort}/KeycloakDB,security-domain="KeycloakDatabaseLogin")
end-if
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Change IP settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Public interface listen on all IPs
/interface=public:write-attribute(name="inet-address",value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}")

# Change http and https ports
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding="management- http":write-attribute(name="port",value="${adminPort}")
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding="http":write-attribute(name="port",value="${httpPort}")
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding="https":write-attribute(name="port",value="${httpsPort}")
```

It worked perfectly.
With version 4.5.0.Final of Keycloak, I have the follwoing error when running the script :

```
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "response-headers" => {
        "operation-requires-reload" => true,
        "process-state" => "reload-required"
    }
}
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "response-headers" => {
        "operation-requires-reload" => true,
        "process-state" => "reload-required"
    }
}
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "response-headers" => {
        "operation-requires-reload" => true,
        "process-state" => "reload-required"
    }
}
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "response-headers" => {
        "operation-requires-reload" => true,
        "process-state" => "reload-required"
    }
}
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "response-headers" => {
        "operation-requires-reload" => true,
        "process-state" => "reload-required"
    }
}
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "response-headers" => {
        "operation-requires-reload" => true,
        "process-state" => "reload-required"
    }
}
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "response-headers" => {
        "operation-requires-reload" => true,
        "process-state" => "reload-required"
    }
}
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "response-headers" => {
        "operation-requires-reload" => true,
        "process-state" => "reload-required"
    }
}
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "response-headers" => {
        "operation-requires-reload" => true,
        "process-state" => "reload-required"
    }
}
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "response-headers" => {
        "operation-requires-reload" => true,
        "process-state" => "reload-required"
    }
}
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "response-headers" => {
        "operation-requires-reload" => true,
        "process-state" => "reload-required"
    }
}
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "response-headers" => {
        "operation-requires-reload" => true,
        "process-state" => "reload-required"
    }
}
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "response-headers" => {
        "operation-requires-reload" => true,
        "process-state" => "reload-required"
    }
}
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0211: Cannot resolve expression '${httpPort}'",
    "rolled-back" => true,
    "response-headers" => {"process-state" => "reload-required"}
}
```

It doesn't replace the ${xxx} by the value passed in as -D in the command line.
I don't understand why.
Can anyone help me ?

Thank you,

Seb

Comment: can you try instead of `-DhttpPort`/`DhttpsPort` to pass it as `-Djboss.https.port=8444`and `-Djboss.http.port=8081` and update keycloak_wildfly.cli accordingly?
P.S. I am not sure whether it is important, `/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding="management- http"`  in my config `"management-http"` is without white space between minus and http

Comment: I replace the port properties by jboss.http.port, jboss.https.port and jboss.management.http.port, and it seems it like it (at least it doesn't complain anymore). But now, I got `{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0211: Cannot resolve expression 'jdbc:mysql://${mysqlHost}:${mysqlPort}/TelemisKeycloakDB'",
    "rolled-back" => true,
    "response-headers" => {"process-state" => "reload-required"}
}`.